# How do I remove a blank checkbox option for a multiple choice column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, multiple-values, issue-tracking, edit-update-delete

**How do I remove a blank checkbox option for a multiple choice column type that allows multiple items to be selected?**
I am using SP Online. I created a list, with a multiple choice column type, with 3 options in a dropdown list. I also checked the box to allow Users to select multiple items in the dropdown list.

When editing the list, and clicking in that column, Users get my 3 options PLUS a BONUS (LOL) checkbox that is blank. How do I remove this blank check box option? I did not enter anything in the choices that would provide a blank check box.

I am seeing this issue in IE 11 and Chrome.

NOTE - I do not have access to InfoPath or SP Designer.

[image: Blank choice box showing up in a answer options for a multiple choice question type]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. In my list, I am getting only options which are available as choices

Comment: Can you please attach the configuration/column settings for this particular column to your question? Go to List settings-->navigate below to "Columns" section-->click on the column name-->You can see its settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set the default value as blank in the column setting. Edit the column in list settings, and add a default value and check again.

[image]

Comment: I have set default value as blank to one of my multiple selection choice field. But I am not able to see a blank choice as @wisdotpubeditor mentioned in question.

Comment: whether you test in the SharePoint Online or SharePoint On-premise? I can reproduce the issue if set default value as blank in SharePoint Online, but it works as expected in my SharePoint 2013 server.

Comment: I was checking in Modern experience in SharePoint Online. seems like it is having issue with Classic experience/2013, etc.